# Переменная не определена, хотя в цикле была объявлена

Tags: javascript, html, css

Поискав инфу, мне кажется что-то со стеком вызовов связано. Вот код

```
const blinds_items = document.getElementsByClassName('blind');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn_anim');
const blind = Array.from(blinds_items);

btn.onmouseover = ()=>{
    for(let i = 0; i <= blind.length; i++){
        blind[i].style.left += `10px`;
    }
}
```

Пишет в консоль, что `blind[i] is undefined`. Кстати, один раз цикл выполняется, потом выдаёт ошибку.
Но, если я добавляю переменную `j`, которая никак к `i` вроде бы не относится, код работает:

```
const blinds_items = document.getElementsByClassName('blind');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn_anim');
let blind = Array.from(blinds_items);
let j = 0;

btn.onmouseover = ()=>{
    for(let i = 0; i <= blind.length; i++){
        blind[i].style.left += j + 'px';
        j+=10;
    }
}
```

Что происходит, не могу понять

html:

```
<div class="btn_anim">
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <span>Animation</span>
        <div class="string"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b1"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b2"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b3"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b4"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b5"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b6"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b7"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b8"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b9"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b10"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b11"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b12"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b13"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b14"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b15"></div>
        <div class="blind" id="b16"></div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `<=` заменить на `<`

Comment: "что-то со стеком вызовов связано" - кхм, кхм... Что?

Comment: У меня была проблема, в цикле я `i=0` сделал, а чтобы она не только счётчиком выполнения цикла, а ещё и счётчиком для элементов массива была, надо было её объявить с помощью `let`

Comment: Alexey Ten, undefined пропало, а работает цикл также, только для одного срабатывает. И всё тот же вопрос, как переменная `j` повлияло на работу кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const blinds_items = document.getElementsByClassName('blind');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn_anim');
const blind = Array.from(blinds_items);

btn.onmouseover = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < blind.length; i++) {
    blind[i].style.left = `${10 * i}px`;
  }
}
```

```css
.btn_anim {
  position: relative;
}

.blind {
  position: absolute;
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #fa0;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn_anim">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <span>Animation</span>
  <div class="string"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b1"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b2"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b3"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b4"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b5"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b6"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b7"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b8"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b9"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b10"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b11"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b12"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b13"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b14"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b15"></div>
  <div class="blind" id="b16"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А, мой вариант почему не работает?

Comment: @АлексейСухорученко: вполне работает. Только не нужно буквы складывать с цифрами  `blind[i].style.left += `10px`;`

Comment: @АлексейСухорученко: здесь код работает? Значит код рабочий.

Comment: А, пардон, я делал += к элементу с начальной `left: 0`, извиняюсь

Comment: @АлексейСухорученко: нет. Начальное значение там не `0`, а `0px`, поэтому у Вас получалось совсем такое `0px10px`